# Запись переменной в куки-массив

Tags: php, массивы

Есть cookie-массив

```
$APPLICATION->set_cookie("KUPON[]", $arResult["COUPON"]);
```

но `$arResult["COUPON"]` каждый раз перезаписывает массив.

Нужно, чтобы он добавлялся в следующий ключ массива. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

может лучше попробовать так?

```
$k = count($_COOKIE['KUPON']);
$APPLICATION->set_cookie("KUPON[".$k."]", $arResult["COUPON"]);
```

Comment: Наверное размер массива в переменную нужно записывать `$k = count($_COOKIE['KUPON']);` при условии что нумерации идет с нуля.

Comment: @Visman точно, это хотел написать, что то перепустил, Вы правы